# Jquery Datatable Pagination issue in IE9

Tags: jquery, datatables

This is a very simple code.And I am using jQuery Datable v1.9.0.

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/DataTables-1.9.0/media/js/jquery.js"></script>     
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/DataTables-1.9.0/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>     
<link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />     <link href="Styles/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<script language="javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function () {            
    $('#example').dataTable({                 
        "bProcessing": true,                 
        "sAjaxSource": 'txtSource.txt',                 
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"            
});         }); 
</script>
```

But when I click the When I click the page numbers, it shows

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unexpected call to method or property access.

But When I test in Firefox and chrome, this error never occurs.
Can anyone tell me what did I wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: I don't see any immediate problem in this code snippet. Might be something you've left out not knowing it would matter. Is txtSource.txt on the up and up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be an IE specific scope related bug on `line 4613` of `dataTables.js`. 
Just change: `n.blur();` to `$(n).blur();` and it should fix the issue. Also, you should send in a bug report to datatables, explaining the issue.

Comment: No problem. By the way, I was speaking with the author of datatables and he says this was already fixed in the nightly build (available on their website), and will be released in 1.9.1. My quick "hack" works, but may not be the best way to go about it.